# Tuning a cross record UPDATE query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that spans across 200 million records and I am trying to run the following query. The query tries to update the table based on the timestamp from the previous record. Is there anyway to make this query run faster?

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Location Data]
    SET [timestamp_prev] = 
    (
           SELECT [timestamp] FROM [dbo].[Location Data] newTable
               WHERE [dbo].[Location Data].[RowNumber] = (newTable.[RowNumber] + 1)
               AND [dbo].[Location Data].[mmsi] = newTable.[mmsi]
    );
```

Comment: Check your query plan: is it actually performing the correlated subquery, or did it translate it into a self-join? If not, you should do that.

Comment: Which version of `SQL Server` you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a self join:

```
UPDATE
    t1
SET
    t1.[timestamp_prev] = t2.[timestamp]
FROM
    [dbo].[Location Data] t1
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Location Data] t2
     ON t1.[RowNumber] = t2.[RowNumber] + 1 AND
        t1.[mmsi] = t2.[mmsi]
```

If you have indices on the join columns this query might finish before you retire.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would do this using `lag()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ld.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by mmsi order by RowNumber) as prev_timestamp
      from dbo.[Location Data] ld
     )
update toupdate
    set timestamp_prev = prev_timetamp;
```

Then, I would note that updating 200 million records is going to take a long, long, long time.  I would suggest that you generate a new table with the columns you want, then truncate the original table, and re-populate it.

Comment: Nice one **lag**. Didn't know this even existed!

Comment: @Sam [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh231256.aspx) was introduced in `SQL SERVER 2012`

Comment: @Prdp I guess Sam was `LAG`ging behind :-)

Answer (score 0):

An inner join like below might help rather than iterating through all the rows of the table per each row of the table as it would in your nested query.

```sql
UPDATE oldTable
SET oldTable.[timestamp_prev] = newTable.[timestamp]
FROM [dbo].[Location Data] oldTable
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Location Data] newTable
    ON oldTable.[RowNumber] = newTable.[RowNumber] + 1
               AND oldTable.[mmsi] = newTable.[mmsi]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
UPDATE T1 SET
    [timestamp_prev] = T2.[timestamp]
FROM [dbo].[Location Data] T1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Location Data] T2
        ON T1.RowNumber = T2.RowNumber + 1
            AND T1.mmsi = T2.mmsi
WHERE T1.[timestamp_prev] IS NULL;
```

The join should be more efficient and only attempt to update records that do not have a previous timestamp. You could then take another step to add an index on RowNumber, MMSI, and Timestamp_Prev to the table which would then ensure a clean index seek to maximize efficiency.

A simple index like this should be a good start:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_Location_Data_MMSI_RowNumber_Timestamp_Prev   
    ON dbo.[Location Data] (mmsi, RowNumber, Timestamp_Prev) INCLUDE (Timestamp);
```